# drag and drop where drop not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a drag and drop where I am able to drag my text but the value is not dropping. I want my text which is (a),(b),(c),(d) to drop in textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" />
        <style>
            .not_attempted {color:red; font-weight:700;}
            .correct {color:green; font-weight:700;}
            .incorrect {color:red; font-weight:700;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="header1">
                    <div class="heading1">Inside Our Earth</div>
                    <div class="heading2">How to match?</div>
                    <div class="heading3">How to match?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="header2"></div>
            </div>
            <!--header closed-->
            <div class="front_page">
                <div class="fp1">
                    <h1>Instruction</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="fp2">
                    <h2>Match Column <b style="color:#000;">A</b> with Coloumn <b style="color:#000;">B</b> by dragging given letters.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="fp3">
                    <h2>After you have attempted answering all questions, click on the <b style="color:#B30000;">"Submit"</b> button to know the Score</h2>
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="continue" value="Continue"/> 
                <div class="ffooter"><b style="position:absolute;margin-left:680px; margin-top:40px;">Copyright @ 2014 Educo International.inc</b></div>
            </div>
            <!--front_page closed-->
            <div id="element_to_pop_up">
                <div class="e1">How to match?</div>
                <div class="e2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Take the mouse on the top of the button in column <b>B</b>.</span></li>
                        <li><span>When mouse become a hand click and drag.</span></li>
                        <li><span>Place it on the appropriate box in the left column.</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container_top"></div>
                <div class="cntt1">Match Column <b style="color:#000;">A</b> with Coloumn <b style="color:#000;">B</b> by dragging given letters.</div>
                <div class="cntt2">Column (A)</div>
                <div class="cntt3">Column (B)</div>
                <div class="cntt4"></div>
                <div class="cntt5"></div>
                <input type="button" class="new_set" value="New Set" />
                <input type="button" class="done" value="Done" />
                <input type="button" class="soln" value="Solution"  disabled="true"/>
                <input type="button" class="reset" value="Reset all"/>
                <div class="cnt1"></div>
                <div class="cnt2"></div>
                <div class="cnt3"></div>
                <div class="cnt4"></div>
                <div class="cnt5"></div>
                <div class="cnt6"></div>
                <div class="cnt7"></div>
                <div class="cnt8"></div>
                <div class="ans_set1">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="10" value="" class="ans_set1_1" />
                    <br><input type="text"  maxlength="10" class="ans_set1_2" />
                    <br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_3" />
                    <br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_4" />
                </div>
                <div class="ans_set2">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_1" />
                    <br><input type="text"  maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_2" />
                    <br><input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_3" />
                    <br><input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_4" />
                </div>
                <div class="abcd">
                    <div class="a" id="draggable"><b>(a)</b></div>
                    <div class="b" id="draggable"><b>(b)</b></div>
                    <div class="c" id="draggable"><b>(c)</b></div>
                    <div class="d" id="draggable"><b>(d)</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--container closed-->
            <div class="footer"><b style="position:absolute;margin-left:680px; margin-top:40px;">Copyright @ 2014 Educo International.inc</b>
            </div>
            <!--footer closed-->
        </div>
        <!--wrapper closed-->
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var array_i = new Array();
                array_i [0] = {question : "Sima "  ,answer:"5"};
                array_i [1] = {question : "Rocks "  ,answer:"6"};
                array_i [2] = {question : "Mineral "  ,answer:"13"};
                array_i [3] = {question : "Shale "  ,answer:"1"};
                array_i [4] = {question : "Hydrosphere "  ,answer:"24"};
                array_i [5] = {question : "Environment "  ,answer:"1"};
                array_i [6] = {question : "Biosphere "  ,answer:"23"};
                array_i [7] = {question : "Atmosphere "  ,answer:"1"};

            var array_j = new Array();
                array_j [0] = {answer:"Changes into Slate"};
                array_j [1] = {answer:"the materials of the Earth's  crust "};
                array_j [2] = {answer:"have definite chemical composition"};
                array_j [3] = {answer:"made up of Silica and Magnesium"};
                array_j [4] = {answer:"Our surroundings"};
                array_j [5] = {answer:"Domain of water"};
                array_j [6] = {answer:"Blanket of air which surrounds the Earth"};
                array_j [7] = {answer:"Narrow zone where land,water and air interact"};              

                i=0

               $(function () {

                 $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
                     revert: true,
                     helper: 'clone',
                     start: function (event, ui) {
                         $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
                     },
                     stop: function (event, ui) {
                         $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
                     }
                 });
                 $(".ans_set1_1,.ans_set1_2,.ans_set1_3,.ans_set1_4").droppable({
                     accept: ".a,.b,.c,.d",
                     drop: function (event, ui) {
                           var $answer=ui.draggable;
                           var $input=$(event.target);
                           var val=$answer.text();
                           $input.val(val);
                     }
                 });
               });

            $('.new_set').click(function() {
                $('.cnt1,.cnt2,.cnt3,.cnt4,.cnt5,.cnt6,.cnt7,.cnt8').empty();
                i=i+4
                if(i==8) {
                    i=0;
                }

                $(".cnt1").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+1]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt2").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+2]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+1]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt3").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+3]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+2]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt4").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+4]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+3]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt5").append("<b >"+array_j[i]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt6").append("<b>"+array_j[i+1]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt7").append("<b>"+array_j[i+2]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt8").append("<b>"+array_j[i+3]['answer']+"</b>");

                if(i==0) {
                    $('.ans_set1').show();
                    $('.ans_set2').hide();
                }
                if(i==4) {
                    $('.ans_set2').show();
                    $('.ans_set1').hide();
                }
            });
            $('.continue').click(function() {
                $('.heading2,.front_page').hide()
                $('.heading3,.container,.footer').show()
                $(".cnt1").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+1]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i]['question']+"</b>"+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt2").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+2]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+1]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt3").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+3]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+2]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt4").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+4]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+3]['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
                $(".cnt5").append("<b>"+array_j[i]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt6").append("<b>"+array_j[i+1]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt7").append("<b>"+array_j[i+2]['answer']+"</b>");
                $(".cnt8").append("<b>"+array_j[i+3]['answer']+"</b>");
            });
            $('.heading3').mouseover(function() {
                $(".heading3").css({"color":"yellow",'font-size' : '34px'})

                $(this).click(function() {
                    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
                });(jQuery);

                $(this).mouseout(function() {
                    $(".heading3").css({"color":"#FFF",'font-size' : '26px'});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please create a fiddle on this

Comment: it is working on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/959/

Comment: check it now its  working

Answer (score 0):

Change your drop event in your jsfiddle this way:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val($(ui.draggable).text())
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sergeir82/5DCZw/986/

Comment: You right, this code works in Chrome but doesn't work in FF. I have fixed this http://jsfiddle.net/sergeir82/5DCZw/986/

Comment: i am having this problem from last 3 days my code runs perfect on fiddle but not on browser can you help me with this i am facing a lot of problem due to this.not all code only the one with drag and drop where drag is working but drop isnt